# Buggy Reduce/Resolve function?

Tags: equation-solving

It seems to me that this is a clear-cut case of Mathematica actually producing the wrong answer (with no warnings).

I'm trying to express the fact that for any integer, there exists a factorization (even if that factorization is just n = n * 1).  But Mathematica says no.

If I replace the domain with Reals or Complexes, then it says True.

Is this a bug or am I using these functions incorrectly?

```
Resolve[ForAll[n, Exists[{p, q}, p*q == n]], Integers]

(*Out[1]= False*)

Reduce[ForAll[n, Exists[{p, q}, p*q == n]], {n, p, q}, Integers]

(*Out[2]= False*)
```

Comment: `FullSimplify[ForAll[n, Exists[{p, q}, p*q == n]], {n, p, q} \[Element] Integers]` works nicely, though.

Comment: @J.M. Try `FullSimplify[
 ForAll[n, Exists[{p, q}, p/Pi  q/Sqrt@2 == n]], {n, p, q} \[Element] 
  Integers]`

Comment: @bel, now that sure is nasty...

Comment: @J.M. I believe the quantifiers are isolating its variables, so they are not visible to FullSimply's assumptions

Comment: It doesn't  seem a problem of `FullSimplify`, but rather of `Exists/ForAll`. E.g. `Resolve[ForAll[n, Exists[{p, q}, p*q == n]], {n, p, q} \[Element] Integers]` returns `True`.

Comment: @belisarius, `Resolve[ForAll[n, n \[Element] Reals], Primes]` returning `False` doesn't look too different, right?

Comment: @Rojo `Primes` does not work. Try `Resolve[ForAll[n, n \[Element] Reals], #] & /@ {Rationals, Integers, Reals, Complexes}` instead

Comment: The same thing happens when I move the Integers constraint to the condition part of the quantifiers, and change the Resolve domain to Reals, as in

`Resolve[ForAll[n, n \[Element] Integers, 
  Exists[p, p \[Element] Integers, 
   Exists[q, q \[Element] Integers, p*q == n]]], Reals]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a limitation of `Resolve[]`.

As stated in the help:

> Resolve[expr] can in principle always eliminate quantifiers if expr contains only polynomial equations and inequalities over the reals or complexes.

It shouldn't return `False`, though.

**Edit**

I am sure this

```
Trace[Resolve[ForAll[n, Exists[{p, q}, p q == n]], Integers], TraceInternal -> True]
```

must explain what is happening ... but I wrote the relevant notes in the margin of some notebook and I can't find them now :)